# Opening existing log file in apache chainsaw

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, apache-chainsaw

is it possible to open an existing log file generated by log4j in my j2ee application using apache chainsaw, without using any special configurations?

I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks,
Ayusman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the latest developer snapshot of Apache Chainsaw, available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

When the Chainsaw configuration dialog is displayed, choose the 'process a log file' option, click the 'open file' link to browse to your log file and then change the 'log file format' to MESSAGE (you can specify a complete format, but this will at least get your messages into Chainsaw quickly).

For information on how to specify the format completely, see the VFSLogFilePatternReceiver javadoc here: http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/vfs/VFSLogFilePatternReceiver.html

Comment: thanks scott. Though I have not got it working 100%, still something go with. Atleast looks better than 2.0 alpha version.